# Regular Expression to show files with 15 characters

Tags: regex, linux, unix

QUESTION 1 (13 marks) 
On gaul, change your working directory to /bin/ 
(a)What will you get when executing pwd command? Explain why did you get that output?
 
(b) Use a Unix command to display the  file names (do not display any of the directory contents, if any) in the current 
working directory whose names: 
I. (2 marks) are of length exactly 15 characters

This is the only one I can not get done on my assignment, i wrote two regular expressions but i can not tell which one is correct

ls /bin/ | grep -c '([0-9])([a-z])*{1,15}' 
8

ls /bin/ | grep -c '[0-9][a-z]*{1,15}' 
45

it has to only be characters A-Z, 0-9 and _

Comment: "can not tell which one is correct" - huh? you can count, right? One of them is obviously wrong. And the other is either correct or only works for your case but hase a bug. asking about the latter one is fine, but about the former one??

Comment: clearly one of this is wrong, but which one, the 8 just means there are 8 files with 15 characters in the name, and the 45 says there are 45 files with names that contain 15 characters.

Comment: @Anthony, how many files are there?  Can you count the ones that are 15 manually?  If so, that will tell you that one of those is wrong.  However, I think they're *both* wrong, and you shouldn't use regex.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen there are around 700 so i could...but time consuming for 2 marks out of 80.

Comment: even if do it by regex, neither your expression is correct. since you have used {1,15}. it will match one character to 15 characters. not required "exactly 15 characters".

Comment: Solved it, was a problem with how i was reading the question and what the teacher told us in class

Comment: If you're asking for help with homework, please use the "homework" tag (I've added it).

Comment: @Anthony Taylor: one of the skills you have to learn is called **testing**. create a directory with files. some of them 15 char long, some shorter and longer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following ls command is enough for your problem:

```
ls -d ???????????????
```

from ls man page:

```
 -d, --directory
              list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links
```

and 15 "?" means, the name of dir/file should be exactly length of 15.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  It doesn't say to use regex, nor does it restrict it to those characters (actual filenames are not limited to those).

Look at [this documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_01).

Hint: You want to match 15 single characters using a string of one or more of the characters given (?, *, or [).

Comment: well i then used "ls ???????????????" but it includes - and . which he doesnt want, and the whole question is about regex so im assuming he wnats one that uses regex

On gaul, change your working directory to /bin/
(a) (2 marks) What will you get when executing pwd command? Explain why did you get that output? 
(b) Use a Unix command to display the  file names (do not display any of the directory contents, if any) in the current 
working directory whose names: 
I. (2 marks) are of length exactly 15 characters 
II. (2 marks) have a z as the second letter
III. (2 marks) end with i or j

Comment: @Anthony, the question does not ask about regex.  I'm not sure what - is, but try using the `-d` modifier as Kent suggested.  You can do the z and i, j parts with shell globbing too.

Comment: I misread what the teacher wanted, the a-b 0-9 and _ only matter for words. 
This question said with 15 characters, my mistake, its been a long assignment

Comment: @Anthony, for the i, j part see the [bracket expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) docs, particularly #2.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a handy tool for this job:

```
ls /bin | grep -ve "[^A-Za-z_]" | awk '{if (length == 15) print $0}'
```

Comment: well since you have already got the power of grep, we don't need the nuclear head - awk. how about `ls -d|grep -P '^[a-zA-Z_]{15}$'` ?